# How to override magento 2 wishlist model?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am working on module in which I have to **override wishlist.php model** but I can't magento give error when I try to override it. I'm providing you error but can you tell me why its not overriding?

Path of model that I want to override:

```
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php
```

Error that I'm facing:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection::addWishlistFilter()
>   must be an instance of Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist, instance of
>   My\Multiwishlist\Model\Wishlist given, called in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/qv3/app/code/My/Multiwishlist/Model/Wishlist.php on
>   line 375 and defined in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/qv3/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Collection.php:338
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/qv3/app/code/My/Multiwishlist/Model/Wishlist.php(375):
>   Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection->addWishlistFilter(Object(My\Multiwishlist\Model\Wishlist))
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/qv3/app/code/My/Multiwishlist/Model/Wishlist.php(617):
>   My\Multiwishlist\Model\Wishlist->getItemCollection() #2
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/qv3/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/AbstractBlock.php(243):
>   My\Multiwishlist\Model\Wishlist->getItemsCount() #3
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/qv3/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/AbstractBl
>   in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/qv3/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Collection.php
>   on line 338

Answer (score 1):

*If you're injecting a new dependency in extended class, then you need to call the **parent::construct** then pass the reference*

```php
namespace My\Multiwishlist\Model\Wishlist;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlist as ResourceWishlist;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlist\Collection;

class Wishlist extends Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist {
    /**
     * Cache tag
     */
    const CACHE_TAG = 'wishlist';

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'wishlist';

    /**
     * Wishlist item collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection
     */
    protected $_itemCollection;

    /**
     * Store filter for wishlist
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\Store
     */
    protected $_store;

    /**
     * Shared store ids (website stores)
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_storeIds;

    /**
     * Wishlist data
     *
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_wishlistData;

    /**
     * Catalog product
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product
     */
    protected $_catalogProduct;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_date;

    /**
     * @var ItemFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistItemFactory;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Math\Random
     */
    protected $mathRandom;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $dateTime;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_useCurrentWebsite;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var Json
     */
    private $serializer;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistData,
        ResourceWishlist $resource,
        Collection $resourceCollection,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        ItemFactory $wishlistItemFactory,
        CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        $useCurrentWebsite = true,
        /* your injecting class */
        array $data = [],
        Json $serializer = null
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data, $useCurrentWebsite,$productRepository,$catalogProduct,$wishlistData,$storeManager,$date,$wishlistItemFactory,$wishlistCollectionFactory,$productFactory,$mathRandom,$dateTime,);
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
    /* initialize the parameter */
    }

}
```